# Different results in Stata and R with the "same" anova code

Tags: r, output, stata, anova, varying

I have some Stata code and I want to replicate the results in **R**. However, even with the same dataset and, I think, the same code, I get different results in **R** from those in Stata. I think it could be because Stata makes the order of the regression different than keyed in.

Do I need exactly the same order as in Stata to get the same results and how can I do this?

I changed all the variables to factors and tried again but the problem is still there.

I noticed that when I change the order of the explanatory variables I get different results, but I don`t find "the right order" to replicate the Stata results.

Stata code:

```
. anova testm2 c.testm1 i.hptreat c.cortm1 c.cortm2 i.female if inelig == 0 & anyoutv1 == 0     

Number of obs =39    R-squared =0.7048 
Root MSE= 16.0144    Adj R-squared =0.6601 

 Source | Partial SS         df         MS        F    Prob>F
---------------------------------------------------------------
  Model |  20209.281          5   4041.8563     15.76  0.0000
 testm1 |  3516.6527          1   3516.6527     13.71  0.0008   
 hptreat|  1183.5007          1   1183.5007      4.61  0.0391
 cortm1 |  8.5753841          1   8.5753841      0.03  0.8560
 cortm2 |  2810.9353          1   2810.9353     10.96  0.0023
 female |  2557.3444          1   2557.3444      9.97  0.0034
Residual|  8463.2532         33   256.46222  
----------------------------------------------------------------
  Total |  28672.535         38   754.54038
```

**R** code:

```
FosseTest<-aov(testm2~testm1+hptreat+cortm1+cortm2+female,data=X2data)
summary(FosseTest) 

            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
testm1       1  15121   15121  58.962 7.68e-09 ***
hptreat      1    524     524   2.043  0.16228    
cortm1       1     23      23   0.089  0.76715    
cortm2       1   1984    1984   7.735  0.00888 ** 
female       1   2557    2557   9.972  0.00339 ** 
Residuals   33   8463     256                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

You can see that I get totally different values in the replication.

in the X2data Set I already subset the values for `if inelig == 0 & anyoutv1 == 0`

for the reconstruction of the data:

```
dput(X2data)
structure(list(id = c(29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L), inelig = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Analytic sample (keep)", "Ineligible (drop)"
), class = "factor"), ccydrop = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), cortm1v2 = c(0.003, 0.086, 0.047, 0.106, NA, 0.153, 0.086, 
0.005, 0.133, 0.036, 0.03, 0.015, 0.014, 0.111, 0.389, 0.298, 
0.4, 0.215, 0.062, 0.021, 0.075, 0.073, 0.033, 0.243, 0.126, 
0.147, 0.019, 0.048, 0.28, 0.052, 0.039, 0.105, 0.111, 0.133, 
0.065, 0.051, 0.143, 0.127, 0.095), cortm2v2 = c(0.025, 0.167, 
0.059, 0.112, 0.171, 0.183, 0.102, 0.018, 0.08, 0.015, 0.027, 
0.05, 0.025, 0.046, 0.085, 0.144, 0.155, 0.09, 0.057, 0.023, 
0.038, 0.205, 0.035, 0.198, 0.112, 0.211, 0.042, 0.142, 0.328, 
0.076, 0.067, 0.094, 0.245, 0.153, 0.115, 0.127, 0.257, 0.125, 
0.096), cdiffv2 = c(0.022, 0.081, 0.012, 0.006, NA, 0.03, 0.016, 
0.013, -0.053, -0.021, -0.003, 0.035, 0.011, -0.065, -0.304, 
-0.154, -0.245, -0.125, -0.005, 0.002, -0.037, 0.132, 0.002, 
-0.045, -0.014, 0.064, 0.023, 0.094, 0.048, 0.024, 0.028, -0.011, 
0.134, 0.02, 0.05, 0.076, 0.114, -0.002, 0.001), testm1v2 = c(38.72, 
32.77, 32.32, 17.99, 73.58, 80.69, 48.56, 21.92, 27.24, 40.93, 
31.73, 60.05, 38.04, 30.17, 59.07, 26.92, 25.41, 47.81, 63.02, 
34.49, 104.38, 38.08, 30.99, 35.23, 104.81, 49.33, 50.03, 11.65, 
143.57, 48.31, 90.37, 48.56, 41.67, 75.23, 60.56, 39.03, 18.16, 
37.9, 84.5), testm2v2 = c(62.37, 29.23, 27.51, 28.66, 44.67, 
105.48, 42.67, 15.01, 21.33, 10.87, 2.14, 44.53, 35.8, 10.43, 
47.54, 48.5, 38.98, 91.32, 52.94, 22.43, 58.68, 81.63, 34.79, 
38.57, 94.86, 50.83, 55.75, 45.33, 111.62, 65.15, 81.08, 50.08, 
44.86, 58.63, 85.85, 58.69, 16.35, 35.97, 99.08), tdiffv2 = c(23.65, 
-3.54, -4.81, 10.67, -28.91, 24.79, -5.89, -6.91, -5.91, -30.06, 
-29.59, -15.52, -2.24, -19.74, -11.53, 21.58, 13.57, 43.51, -10.08, 
-12.06, -45.7, 43.55, 3.8, 3.34, -9.95, 1.5, 5.72, 33.68, -31.95, 
16.84, -9.29000000000001, 1.52, 3.19, -16.6, 25.29, 19.66, -1.81, 
-1.93, 14.58), testoutv1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Not selected", "Selected"), class = "factor"), 
    cortoutv1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Not selected", "Selected"), class = "factor"), 
    anyoutv1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Not selected", "Selected"), class = "factor"), 
    testoutv2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Not selected", "Selected"), class = "factor"), 
    cortoutv2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Not selected", "Selected"), class = "factor"), 
    anyoutv2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Not selected", "Selected"), class = "factor"), 
    pose1rate = c(6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), pose2rate = c(6L, 
    6L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L), poseratem = c(6, 6.5, 5.5, 
    6.5, 7, 7, 6.5, 7, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 5.5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6.5, 7, 
    7, 7, 6.5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6.5, 7, 6.5, 7, 7, 7, 6.5, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 6.5, 6.5), saldiff = c(24.30555556, 20.83333333, 29.16666667, 
    18.75, 23.61111111, 34.02777778, 18.05555556, 19.44444444, 
    21.52777778, 15.97222222, 22.91666667, 13.88888889, 22.22222222, 
    25, 22.22222222, 22.22222222, 18.05555556, 17.36111111, 22.22222222, 
    27.08333333, 20.83333333, 24.30555556, 22.22222222, 28.47222222, 
    24.30555556, 25, 27.77777778, 22.22222222, 15.97222222, 24.30555556, 
    21.52777778, 19.44444444, 15.97222222, 15.27777778, 15.97222222, 
    24.30555556, 19.44444444, 24.30555556, 15.27777778), sal2manip = c(19.80555556, 
    16.33333333, 24.66666667, 14.25, 19.11111111, 29.52777778, 
    13.55555556, 14.94444444, 17.02777778, 11.47222222, 18.41666667, 
    9.38888889, 17.72222222, 20.5, 17.72222222, 17.72222222, 
    13.55555556, 12.86111111, 17.72222222, 22.58333333, 16.33333333, 
    19.80555556, 17.72222222, 23.97222222, 19.80555556, 20.5, 
    23.27777778, 17.72222222, 11.47222222, 19.80555556, 17.02777778, 
    14.94444444, 11.47222222, 10.77777778, 11.47222222, 19.80555556, 
    14.94444444, 19.80555556, 10.77777778), hptreat = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    female = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), age = c(19L, 
    20L, 20L, 18L, 21L, 20L, 18L, 21L, 35L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 
    18L, 20L, 25L, 18L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 19L, 22L, 
    18L, 19L, 22L, 19L, 20L, 28L, 28L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 25L, 20L, 
    25L, 23L), cort1a1 = c(0.004, 0.085, 0.049, 0.107, 0.486, 
    0.159, 0.088, 0.004, 0.138, 0.035, 0.03, 0.018, 0.017, 0.111, 
    0.39, 0.292, 0.396, 0.213, 0.065, 0.022, 0.074, 0.077, 0.035, 
    0.241, 0.126, 0.154, 0.021, 0.05, 0.296, 0.054, 0.04, 0.109, 
    0.114, 0.133, 0.063, 0.055, 0.149, 0.134, 0.098), cort1a2 = c(0.001, 
    0.086, 0.045, 0.105, 0.482, 0.147, 0.085, 0.005, 0.127, 0.037, 
    0.031, 0.013, 0.011, 0.111, 0.389, 0.304, 0.405, 0.218, 0.059, 
    0.02, 0.076, 0.069, 0.032, 0.246, 0.126, 0.141, 0.017, 0.046, 
    0.264, 0.051, 0.038, 0.101, 0.109, 0.133, 0.068, 0.048, 0.137, 
    0.12, 0.092), cort2a1 = c(0.027, 0.174, 0.056, 0.111, 0.175, 
    0.179, 0.103, 0.021, 0.079, 0.014, 0.028, 0.051, 0.024, 0.051, 
    0.083, 0.148, 0.156, 0.086, 0.062, 0.024, 0.038, 0.209, 0.036, 
    0.199, 0.114, 0.207, 0.041, 0.141, 0.333, 0.078, 0.065, 0.088, 
    0.238, 0.157, 0.119, 0.132, 0.268, 0.132, 0.099), cort2a2 = c(0.023, 
    0.161, 0.062, 0.113, 0.166, 0.188, 0.101, 0.016, 0.081, 0.015, 
    0.026, 0.049, 0.026, 0.041, 0.086, 0.139, 0.154, 0.093, 0.052, 
    0.022, 0.038, 0.202, 0.034, 0.198, 0.111, 0.215, 0.042, 0.142, 
    0.324, 0.075, 0.068, 0.101, 0.252, 0.149, 0.111, 0.123, 0.247, 
    0.118, 0.093), cortm1 = c(0.0024999999, 0.085500002, 0.046999998, 
    0.106, 0.484, 0.153, 0.086499996, 0.0044999998, 0.13249999, 
    0.035999998, 0.0305, 0.0155, 0.014, 0.111, 0.38949999, 0.29800001, 
    0.4005, 0.2155, 0.061999999, 0.021, 0.075000003, 0.072999999, 
    0.033500001, 0.24349999, 0.126, 0.14749999, 0.018999999, 
    0.048, 0.28, 0.052499998, 0.039000001, 0.105, 0.1115, 0.133, 
    0.065499999, 0.0515, 0.14300001, 0.127, 0.094999999), cortm2 = c(0.025, 
    0.1675, 0.059, 0.112, 0.1705, 0.18350001, 0.102, 0.0185, 
    0.079999998, 0.0145, 0.027000001, 0.050000001, 0.025, 0.046, 
    0.0845, 0.1435, 0.155, 0.089500003, 0.057, 0.023, 0.037999999, 
    0.20550001, 0.035, 0.19850001, 0.1125, 0.211, 0.041499998, 
    0.1415, 0.3285, 0.076499999, 0.066500001, 0.094499998, 0.245, 
    0.153, 0.115, 0.1275, 0.25749999, 0.125, 0.096000001), cdiff = c(0.022500001, 
    0.082000002, 0.012000002, 0.0060000047, -0.31349999, 0.03050001, 
    0.015500002, 0.014, -0.052499995, -0.021499999, -0.0034999996, 
    0.034500003, 0.011, -0.064999998, -0.30500001, -0.15450001, 
    -0.2455, -0.12599999, -0.004999999, 0.0020000003, -0.037000004, 
    0.13250001, 0.0014999993, -0.044999987, -0.013500005, 0.063500002, 
    0.022499999, 0.093499996, 0.048500001, 0.024, 0.0275, -0.010499999, 
    0.13350001, 0.019999996, 0.049500003, 0.075999998, 0.11449999, 
    -0.0020000041, 0.001000002), test1a1 = c(39.87, 33.22, 32.52, 
    19.74, 78.85, 83.51, 48.37, 22.31, 28.17, 41.44, 32.92, 61.4, 
    40.31, 30.36, 59.44, 27.52, 26.14, 46.75, 63.73, 34.03, 98.47, 
    36.62, 30.26, 37.15, 105.64, 47.99, 50.15, 11.33, 149.12, 
    48.57, 92.04, 51.22, 42.25, 77.07, 62.75, 38.8, 17.91, 40.28, 
    88.47), test1a2 = c(37.58, 32.32, 32.12, 16.25, 68.31, 77.88, 
    48.75, 21.53, 26.32, 40.42, 30.55, 58.7, 35.78, 29.97, 58.7, 
    26.32, 24.69, 48.87, 62.32, 34.95, 110.29, 39.53, 31.72, 
    33.32, 103.99, 50.67, 49.9, 11.97, 138.02, 48.05, 88.7, 45.89, 
    41.08, 73.39, 58.38, 39.25, 18.41, 35.53, 80.54), test2a1 = c(64.22, 
    29.43, 27.98, 28.17, 46.14, 105.92, 43.68, 16.41, 21.42, 
    11.35, 1.66, 44.17, 38.58, 11.11, 48.57, 48.31, 39.71, 92.04, 
    52.73, 22.3, 58.23, 82.01, 35.76, 39.59, 94.06, 50.52, 55.82, 
    45.91, 115.13, 67.59, 82.97, 49.89, 45.09, 57.86, 86.76, 
    58.83, 16.53, 36.7, 100.4), test2a2 = c(60.53, 29.04, 27.04, 
    29.14, 43.2, 105.05, 41.66, 13.62, 21.25, 10.39, 2.63, 44.9, 
    33.02, 9.75, 46.52, 48.7, 38.25, 90.59, 53.15, 22.57, 59.14, 
    81.24, 33.81, 37.55, 95.66, 51.14, 55.69, 44.74, 108.1, 62.71, 
    79.18, 50.27, 44.63, 59.39, 84.94, 58.55, 16.16, 35.24, 97.75
    ), testm1 = c(38.724998, 32.77, 32.32, 17.995001, 73.580002, 
    80.695, 48.560001, 21.92, 27.245001, 40.93, 31.735001, 60.049999, 
    38.044998, 30.165001, 59.07, 26.92, 25.415001, 47.810001, 
    63.025002, 34.490002, 104.38, 38.075001, 30.99, 35.235001, 
    104.815, 49.330002, 50.025002, 11.65, 143.57001, 48.310001, 
    90.370003, 48.555, 41.665001, 75.230003, 60.564999, 39.025002, 
    18.16, 37.904999, 84.504997), testm2 = c(62.375, 29.235001, 
    27.51, 28.655001, 44.669998, 105.485, 42.669998, 15.015, 
    21.334999, 10.87, 2.145, 44.535, 35.799999, 10.43, 47.544998, 
    48.505001, 38.98, 91.315002, 52.939999, 22.434999, 58.685001, 
    81.625, 34.785, 38.57, 94.860001, 50.830002, 55.755001, 45.325001, 
    111.615, 65.150002, 81.074997, 50.080002, 44.860001, 58.625, 
    85.849998, 58.689999, 16.344999, 35.970001, 99.074997), tdiff = c(23.650002, 
    -3.5349998, -4.8099995, 10.66, -28.910004, 24.790001, -5.8900032, 
    -6.9049997, -5.9100018, -30.060001, -29.59, -15.514999, -2.2449989, 
    -19.735001, -11.525002, 21.585001, 13.564999, 43.505001, 
    -10.085003, -12.055002, -45.694996, 43.549999, 3.7950001, 
    3.3349991, -9.9550018, 1.5, 5.7299995, 33.675003, -31.955009, 
    16.84, -9.2950058, 1.5250015, 3.1949997, -16.605003, 25.285, 
    19.664997, -1.8150005, -1.9349976, 14.57), feelpower = structure(c(2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("2", "3", "Not at all", 
    "Very much"), class = "factor"), incharge = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "3", "Not at all", 
    "Very much"), class = "factor"), powm = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
    1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
    6L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1.5", "2", "2.5", 
    "3", "3.5", "Not at all", "Very much"), class = "factor"), 
    diceroll = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please share the data you are using? E.g. with `dput()`

Comment: I hope thats the right way and you can use the data now :)

Comment: That data display is friendly to R users but not Stata users who don't use R routinely. The equivalent in Stata would be the results of `dataex testm2 testm1 hptreat cortm1 cortm2 female` for the observations you're using. On the face of it, the difference here is likely to be over which variables are treated as factors and which as continuous variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you mind telling me how I should construct the r code to get an euivalent result to the output in stata? Because at the moment the variables hptreat and female are factor variables (because of the i. in the stata code) and the other values (testm1,testm2, cortm1,cortm2) are numeric because of the c. in the stata code. What else can I change to get the right values?

Comment: If you were addressing me, then sorry, but I can't advise on use of R. Fortunately, your question now appears answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same results in `R` using `drop1(FosseTest, test = "F")`. This will test the effect of leaving one of the variables off the `aov`.

```
drop1(FosseTest, test = "F")

# 
# Single term deletions
# 
# Model:
# testm2 ~ testm1 + hptreat + cortm1 + cortm2 + female
#         Df Sum of Sq     RSS    AIC F value    Pr(>F)    
# <none>                8463.3 221.82                      
# testm1   1    3516.7 11979.9 233.37 13.7122 0.0007751 ***
# hptreat  1    1183.5  9646.8 224.92  4.6147 0.0391333 *  
# cortm1   1       8.6  8471.8 219.86  0.0334 0.8560279    
# cortm2   1    2810.9 11274.2 231.00 10.9604 0.0022605 ** 
# female   1    2557.3 11020.6 230.11  9.9716 0.0033895 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

`summary(FosseTest)` displays the sequential effect of addeding the variables one after another.

There was a different way how to access this, but at the moment I can't remember...